# Specify custom php.ini to use with WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I have a Linux crontab that runs a bash script.  In the bash script, it executes a few wp-cli commands.  I want to apply a custom php.ini file when wp-cli runs to ensure timeouts are not an issue.  Is there a setting/method that allows you to set a custom php.ini to use with wp-cli?

Thanks!

Comment: Timeouts shouldn't be an issue for CLI commands, your CLI PHP should have a different `php.ini` to that used for serving webpages, but that's a PHP specific server issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If executing PHP scripts directly on command line, you can try the [-d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081565/6055797) option.

Another way is to make use of the `WP_CLI` constant:

```
if ( defined('WP_CLI') && WP_CLI ) {
    // Load custom PHP configurations here.
}
```